# Adding all the tags <a> in a variable, except some with specific Id names

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have a variable called *notincluded*:

```
var notincluded = “one,two,three”
```

Lets say for some reasons I cannot change the form of this variable. How can I transform *“one,two,three”* into something that can be placed in:

```
var ids = $("a:not([href])").not ('notincluded');
```

So eventually I can have all the   tags (anchors) in **ids** , except the anchors named  one, two and three.

Sorry if I could not explain it well enough, please let me know if I can add more details to make it clear, thanks.

Comment: Do you really have `“one,two,three”`? That's not valid syntax.

Comment: `one,two,three` are ids of the `a`?

Comment: yes, the fact is that the "one,two,three" comes from an application, so I need to process the variable that is like this and separate one, two and three as id names and place them in the code so they will not be included in the list of <a> tags in the second variable (ids). I would figure it out if I could change the form of "one,two,three" but I cannot, so I need to transform it the way that can be placed in the second code, and be removed from the list of <a> tags that will be in ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to transform `notincluded` with regepx inserting `#` in front of each id:

```
var notincluded = "one,two,three";
var ids = $("a:not([href])").not(notincluded.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g, '#'));
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zvmLc7oc/

Comment: But here we still have 1 included in the ids.

Comment: Can't see, which one?

Answer (score 2):

Add #(id) prefix before on the string notincluded

```
var notincluded = "one,two,three";

notincluded  = '#'+notincluded.split(",").join(',#')

var ids = $("a:not([href])").not(notincluded);
```

Comment: I know it would fix the issue. I cannot change the form of "one,two,three". It comes from a third party app just like this "one,two,three" and these are id names.

Answer (score 1):

Add some classes to the element, in which you should not include that in a variable.

For example, try like this:

```
var ids = $( "div" ).not( ".not" );
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You're using the wrong quotes `“ != "` so `“one,two,three” != "one,two,three"`

2) `'notincluded'` is a string, not a variable, so `'notincluded' != notincluded`

3) I think what you want is:

```
                                 // build a selector of ids
var ids = $('a:not([href])').not('#'+ notincluded.split(',').join('#,'))
```